# How to set radial ProgressTimer progress to start increasing from the bottom(6 o'clock) to top?

Tags: cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-js, cocos2d-x-2.x

Currently if you apply ProgressTimer on a sprite and set any percentage, it will start its progress from top mid (12 o'clock) to whatever the percentage provided. I want to start the progress from bottom mid (6 o'clock), i played with the setMidpoint and setBarChangeRate but could not produce the required result. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: My bad. I just achieved the required result by setting the rotation of the image to 180.